# DBeaver periodic workspace save issue

Tags: java, html, dbeaver

I'm working with DBeaver Oracle server.
I'm getting a periodic error about workspace save.
I tried google to find a solution but all I found was meta data related explanations. I am new to DBeaver so if anyone knows this problem and a solution please help.
Following is the error I got.

```
Could not write metadata for '/.dbeaver-temp'.
/home/engineer/.dbeaver/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources
/.projects/.dbeaver-temp/.markers.snap (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729085/eclipse-periodic-workspace-save-has-encountered-a-problem, close dbeaver then delete all the files and folders in /home/engineer/.dbeaver/.metadata/ and restart the dbeaver seem to a simple solution.

Comment: tried, but still getting the same notice

Comment: erhun Thanks for the link. i'll try the solutions in that link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to delete `.metadata` folder. May be it will work. 
 **P.S. make sure to backup folder**

Comment: Thank you Sandun Chathuranga. I have deleted the `.metadata` folder and notice is not showing up since then. I think the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One can also create a folder and file in the said path it will work

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects.dbeaver-temp

if on the windows use dos command to create the folder starting the . period

I hope this helps as well. it worked for me , my eclipse version was neon